# mysql-connector . infinite wait on ' chunk = self.sock.recv(4 - packet_len)'

Tags: python, ubuntu, server, connection, mysql-connector

I run many scripts to another server, To database mysql server and before little time my scripts they are in infinite wait when it send request to the database. When I click on ctrl+c i get this error

```
  File "running_remote_servers.py", line 32, in get_data_server
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 267, in _send_cmd
    return self._socket.recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 241, in recv_plain
    chunk = self.sock.recv(4 - packet_len)
```

how can i fix this please ? it's sur there is not probleme with the database server but the probleme is from my current server who I run the python script.

Comment: is the query actually running on the server? Could it be that the server puts your query on wait (e.g., if other users/connections have locked some tables and didn't release them yet)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the problem was that I had many opened connection in the same server, when I closed all the connections its work.